# What difference between stored procedure and query in application

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, query-performance

What difference between stored procedure and query in application.
Performance , network load, server load and speed
Thank you very much

Comment: Will depend very much onwhat the sp does. You can use them to reduce network traffic,but first, determine where your **resources**are bottle-necked, then try to pick the low-handing fruit!

Answer (score 2):

You typically have less "chatty" communication between the client and SQL Server when you use stored procedures since you encapsulate several operations in the proc, something that  would typically result in several interactions between the client and the server.

It is also IMO far easier to instrument the SQL code from a performance perspective when using stored procedures. Capture them in a trace (or some other method), read through the SQL with a sense of context (which you have less of when you only see SQL submitted from the app), try different things in the SQL, add hints like RECOMPILE if neccesary without having to do changes in the client app. Etc.